# FTP quota exceeded but its not !

Tags: hosting, ftp

I have a hosting package with 100MB and i deleted all the files in the FTP account and uploaded 55MB but it exceeds the 100MB

even i deleted all the files in the FTP folder but the disk quota says that 44MB is used :S

Comment: I don't think this is a suitable question for Server Fault. However, without more details (which hosting package/provider etc.) we won't be able to direct you at the most appropriate Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just reached a quota that's more granular than the one posted on their signup page.

Even with >80% monthly bandwidth remaining, I've seen the 'quota exceeded' message in my ftp client if I'm reaching a certain amount within an hour.

As others have said, talk to your provider.

Answer (score 1):

Generally Speaking, calculating quotas in realtime is the hell of a job (with growing amounts of data). So it is very likely that there is an automated process taking place every once in a while (i.e. every night) that calculates and updates your quota usage.

You should be talking to your provider, how and when quotas are getting calculated and updated.